# Send an Email in a form

Tags: php, forms

i have a question. I have created a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="input.php">
  <b>Conference</b><br>
  Username:<br> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nome Cognome" size="20"><br>
  Email: <br> &ensp;<input type="email" name="email" size="20" placeholder="email"><br>
  Object:<br><textarea name="object" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Specificare oggetto Videoconferenza"></textarea><br>
  Data: <br>&ensp;<input  type="date" name="data"  ><br>
</form>
```

I want to know if it is possible also send and email with the data inserted in the form.

So that the user compiles the form and is automatically inserted into the DB and sent to an administrator

Thank you

Comment: "_I want to know if it is possible also send and email with the data inserted in the form._" Yes, it is.

Comment: @kerbholz 
Thanks for the answer very nice friend! Can I do it directly in the form or with something external?

Comment: Not directly in the form, but in your `input.php` after you validated/sanitized your data and added it to your database. Here's the [mail manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: But can i do this in local server?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can put values like form.but you not exactly same as html does, so make input field or ul li tag by use them you can send your data as form